# laravel validation rules for multiple value

Tags: laravel

I am trying to validate form data using laravel validation. I want to validate some fields based on some conditions.

Suppose I have three input fields - input1, input2, input3

input3 is required or not it depends on input1 and input2.

1. if the input1 value is 1, input3 is not required.
   N.B. what input2 is that doesn't matter.
2. if the input2 value is 2, input3 is not required.
   N.B. what input1 is that doesn't matter.

Except for the above two cases, Input3 is required.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Rule::requiredIf()` to construct a more complex scenario - [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-if)

```php
Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'input3' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($request) {
        return !!($request->input1 !== 1 || $request->input2 !== 2);
    }),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this validation with 2 approaches, I have attached both approaches below.

**Approach First:**

With approach first, you don't need any additional class included in your code, you can pass a callback function with the validate function.

```
    public function validationCaseFirst(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            "input3" => [function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
                if ($request->input1 != 1 || $request->input2 != 2)
                    $fail("The input 3 field is required when input1 is not 1 or input2 is not 2");
            }],
        ]);
    }
```

**Approach Second:**

With approach second, you need `Illuminate\Validation\Rule` class included in your controller, and then you can use the static method requiredIf with the Rule Class.

```
    use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

    public function validationCaseSecound(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->validate([
            "input3" => Rule::requiredIf($request->input1 != 1 || $request->input2 != 2),
        ]);
    }
```